# Exclude column in redshift spectrum sql queries

Tags: sql, amazon-s3, amazon-redshift, amazon-redshift-spectrum

In my table having columns col1,col2.....coln

I want to

```
select all columns except col1
```

instead of writing select col2,col3.... coln from  I can  specify

```
select * from <table name> except col1
```

Select all column excluding one column

Comment: That's not possible.

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this-

```
-- create a temporary copy of your table
SELECT * INTO temp_table FROM original_table;

-- drop the column you don't need
ALTER TABLE temp_table DROP COLUMN col1;

-- select all columns
SELECT * FROM temp_table;

-- drop the temporary table
DROP TABLE temp_table;
```